# How to get copy-paste data with QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

The user wants to copy a text in external text editor and paste it into the `QTableView` using `Command + v` on Mac or 'Control + v' hotkeys.

I have implemented `keyPressEvent` which tracks every user keyboard action. But how to get the pated data from the clipboard?

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class View(QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(View, self).__init__(parent=None)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.matches(QKeySequence.Copy):
            print 'Ctrl + C'
        if event.matches(QKeySequence.Paste):
            print 'Ctrl + V'
        QTableView.keyPressEvent(self, event)


app = QApplication([])
view = View()
view.show()
qApp.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: You want when you run Ctrl + V you create an item ?, this will not be done automatically, so you must do it through a model. If you paste the text in what position do you want it to stick since it is a QTableView?

Comment: Print the pasted text or data would be just fine for this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use an object of the class [`QClipboard`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html), in this case we obtain it through `QApplication`, to obtain the text we use [`QClipboard::text()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#text) and to paste a text we use [`QClipboard::setText()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#setText)

In your case:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
    if event.matches(QKeySequence.Copy):
        print('Ctrl + C')
        clipboard.setText("some text")
    if event.matches(QKeySequence.Paste):
        print(clipboard.text())
        print('Ctrl + V')
    QTableView.keyPressEvent(self, event)
```